# Filter coming result in same column

Tags: sql

| Pointid | Productid |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 24 |
| 6 | 24 |
| 6 | 25 |
| 6 | 26 |
| 7 | 24 |
| 7 | 25 |
| 7 | 26 |
| 7 | 27 |

For the query:

```sql
select distinct pointid
from mytable
where productid in (24,25,26)
```

The result is: `5,6,7`

But I want only 6.
No more No less..

How can I do it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If u want only 6 then take only 6. If u want all the data with product id 24,25,26 then u will get 5,6,7 its only natural. Be clear with your question please.

Comment: if I write 24 the result should be 5...    if I write (24,25,26) the result should be 6... if I write (24,25,26,27) the result should be 7

Comment: @olcay you need to explain the logic you are using... each productid has multiple pointid's - how are you choosing one? The maximum?

Comment: Are you saying you want the product `PointId`s that have `ProductId`s which exactly match a list, for example, `24, 25, 26`?

Comment: I will score each product. plus I will score these products in combination. I will give 5 point for the pen. for the  pen and the eraser I wil give 6 points. for the pen ,eraser and notbook I will give 10 points... so I will need the pointid that I select product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal is to find those `pointid` where their `productid` are **EXACTLY** `24, 25, 26`. Importantly: **no more, no less**.

In essence, you are requiring two distinct conditions:

- 1. That the `pointid` contains **ALL** of the following `productid`s; `24, 25, 26`, and,
- 2. That the `pointid` does not contain any other `productid`.

Both conditions can be addressed with a `having` clause.

- 1. You make sure that it contains all of the `productid`s. As there are 3, you want the count of the `productid`s that match `24, 25, 26`, to be exactly 3: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN productid in (24, 25, 26) THEN productid END) = 3`.
- 2. You want it to contain **no other `productid`**. So you make sure that the total value of distinct `productid`s is 3: `COUNT(DISTINCT productid) = 3`.

The following query puts it all together:

```sql
SELECT pointid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY pointid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN productid in (24, 25, 26) THEN productid END) = 3
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT productid) = 3
;
```

If you wanted to do something similar with different conditions (as you mentioned in your comments):

- Replace `24,25,26`, for the `productid`s that you want to check.
- Replace `3` for the number of `productid`s that you are checking.

Comment: I want to learn only pointid that have 24,25,26 productid...the result only should be 6.. already I  dont know pointis

Comment: I see, I had completely misunderstood your question. I just edited my solution. This new one should work.

Comment: Sorry, I just did a couple of small edits. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: Andres silva it is working but How can I revise For only (24) or (24,25,26,27)

Comment: I just edited my answer to explain the reasoning better. This should make it essier for you to adapt the solution to your different needs. If you consider this to be the correct solution, please mark it as such by clicking on the check mark next to it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I will score each product. plus I will score these products in combination. I will give 5 point for the pen. for the  pen and the eraser I wil give 6 points. for the pen ,eraser and notbook I will give 10 points... so I will need the pointid that I select product.

Comment: All you need to do is change `24, 25, 26` for whatever you need, and then change `3` for the number of `productid`s that you are searching for (eg, if it is `24, 25, 26, 27`, then change `3` for `4`).

Comment: SELECT pointid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY pointid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN productid in (24, 25, 26,27) THEN productid END) = 3
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT productid) = 4   ....sorry this is not working

Comment: Yo still have a 3 at "... (24, 25, 26, 27) THEN productid END) = 3". Change it for a 4.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select pointid
from mytable
group by pointid
having sum(case when productid in (24, 25, 26) then 1 else 0 end) = 3 and
       count(*) = 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9bbaad6f6f9caff7522dbd80617f3236) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @olcay . . . I see you want an exact match.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: @olcay . . . Remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the rows where `productid` is in(24,25,26) and `pointid` count is maximum. Then try this

```
SELECT pointid FROM mytable
GROUP BY pointid HAVING productid in(24,25,26)
ORDER BY COUNT(pointid) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Then how can u say u only need pointid 6?

Comment: if I write 24 the result should be 5...    if I write (24,25,26) the result should be 6... if I write (24,25,26,27) the result should be 7

Comment: @olcay try now. I updated it to take the maximum count of point id